# asp.net: Iterating over multiple repeater.items collections

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iterator, .net-2.0, repeater

I have a number of idential repeaters, and I need to iterate through all of the items.  I currently have:

```
 For Each item In rpt1.Items
    ...do some stuff
 Next

 For Each item In rpt2.Items
    ...exact same code
 Next
```

Is there a simple way to reduce this to a single For Each ... Next loop?

Edit:  There are a number of local vars involved in "do some stuff", which is why I can't just pass the item into a function - the call would have to include about 8 ByRef params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put your code into a separate method:

```
For Each item In rpt1.Items
    DoSomethingWith(item)
Next
For Each item In rpt2.Items
    DoSomethingWith(item)
Next 

...

Sub DoSomethingWith(item As RepeaterItem)
   ... put your common code here ...
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**: If you have lots of local variables, using a local lambda might be an option:

```
Dim doSomething = Sub(item As RepeaterItem)
                      ... do some stuff using all available local variables
                  End Sub

For Each item In rpt1.Items
    doSomething(item)
Next
For Each item In rpt2.Items
    doSomething(item)
Next
```

---

**EDIT**: One more option, which does not require lambdas:

```
For Each rpt In New Repeater() {rpt1, rpt2}
    For Each item In rpt.Items
        ...do something with item and rpt
   Next
Next
```

Comment: I thought about this, but there are a number of local vars involved - the call to DoSomethingWith would have to have about 8 ByRef params, and something about that just doesn't feel right.

Comment: @chris: If you use Visual Studio 2010, you can use multi-line lambdas to capture the local variables. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: @chris: I've added one more option, which does not require lambdas. It basically creates an array of the two repeaters and iterates through this array in an outer loop.

Comment: That last option - with the array of Repeaters - works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In C# I'd do something like this in LINQ, not sure if you can convert that to VB.

```
var rep1 = new Repeater();
var rep2 = new Repeater();
var rep3 = new Repeater();

foreach (var item in rep1.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
    .Concat(rep2.Items.OfType<ListItem>())
    .Concat(rep3.Items.OfType<ListItem>()))
{
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this won't work - we're only using asp.net 2.0 for this project.

Answer (score 1):

This is C#, but it will check all the controls and child controls for repeater controls and then do whatever you needed it to do.

Call it like this:

```
DoSomethingWithMyRepeaterControls(Form.Controls);
```

The method:

```
private static void DoSomethingWithMyRepeaterControls(ControlCollection controls)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
            {
                if(control.HasControls())
                    DoSomethingWithMyRepeaterControls(control.Controls);

                if(control.GetType() == typeof(Repeater))
                {
                    //here there be tygers   
                }
            }
        }
```